# Seam 2.2.0 URL rewrite not working

Tags: url-rewriting, seam

I'm trying a simple example of URL rewriting, but it's not working for me. I'm using Seam 2.2.0 deployed to JBoss 5.1.0.

My pages.xml contains:

```
 <page view-id="/html/index.xhtml">
    <rewrite pattern="/home" />
</page>
```

and

```
<page view-id="/html/common/redirect.xhtml" action="#{redirectAction.redirect}">
    <rewrite pattern="/link" />
    ...
```

My components.xml contains:

```
    <web:rewrite-filter view-mapping="*.seam"/>
```

As far as I can tell from the documentation, that should be all I need. However, none of the internal links appear different, and if enter the URL: http://mysite/home or mysite/link?param=something, I just get a 404 page. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to move from the Tuckey Rewrite Filter to Seam. After some trial and error I finally noticed that I had a page.xml for the view I but added the  pattern in the main pages.xml. The former seems to overwrite the latter.

Answer (score 0):

From the seam documentation:

"The  view-mapping parameter must match the Servlet mapping defined for the Faces Servlet in the  web.xml file. If omitted, the rewrite filter assumes the pattern  *.seam."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you approach is not working. But don't forget that you can use `viewName.page.xml` file for the same purpose.
For an example since the name of your page is `index.xhtml` you have to create the `index.page.xml` file inside the same folder which contains the `index.xhtml` file(in your case inside the `html` folder).

In `index.page.xml` file add this.

```
<rewrite pattern="/home" />
```

As you are already doing your `component.xml` file should contain the line

```
<web:rewrite-filter view-mapping="*.seam"/>
```

Deploy again and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though after three years, I don't even have access to that project to test your theory. IIRC, I did solve that problem and it was caused by my XML files being overlaid during the build process. I remember an answer here pointing me in the right direction, and I accepted it. Now both are gone, and I'm not sure how that happened.