# WordPress url rewriting for Java

Tags: java, seam, url-rewriting

I currently work with Java JBoss Seam.

I've been looking for some information on how to url rewriting, to accomplish something like what WordPress does.

In WordPress you can create a page and give out a url for that page. Thats pretty sweet.

How could I accomplish that in Java? preferably in Seam?

Some reading would be great.

Regards

RD

Comment: It might help if you could post the web server that you are using since that is probably what matters in this case. (not exactly sure about using Java for web design, so that's why this is just a recommendation)

Answer (score 1):

I've used the Paul Tuckey's Url Rewrite Filter in a number of projects:

http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

It uses an XML file to configure inbound and outbound rewriting rules.  Both regular expressions and wildcards are supported.  It's probably the way to go if your framework doesn't support the URL patterns you want.

A URL rewriting module on your web server is also an option, but I lean towards solutions that let me pack all of the required configuration files in the WAR.

Answer (score 0):

this question has a problem of it not working, but it looks like there was a comment on how to get it working, im not sure if it will help you though, good luck.

[Seam 2.2.0 URL rewrite not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440641/seam-2-2-0-url-rewrite-not-working)

and here's another example, probably more helpful.

http://www.jtict.com/blog/seam-form-url-rewriting/

one more resource.

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html/events.html#d0e5112